# SyntaxError: Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <Route> with react-router-dom v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I want my react app to have urls that look like `localhost:3000/projects/construction` and `localhost:3000/services/landscape`.

The [docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview) for react-router-dom say you can nest routes like so:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="invoices" element={<Invoices />}>
        <Route path="sent" element={<SentInvoices />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

Why then does my app fail with an `Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <Route>` error when I do this?

```
<BrowserRouter>
 <Routes>
  <Route index element={<Home />} />
  <Route path='/projects' element={<Projects />}>
   <Route path='/construction' element={<Construction />}>
  </Route>
  <Route path='/services' element={<Services />}>
   <Route path='/landscape' element={<Landscape />}>
  </Route>
  <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
  <Route path='/contact' element={<Contact />} />
  <Route path='*' element={<Navigate to='/' replace />} />
 </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

---

*Edit: the selected answer said to close the tags, and that was right, but that makes all pages render blank (unless I uncomment the nested routes).*

**App.js**

```
import Services from './components/Services.js'
import Landscape from './components/Landscape.js'

function App() {
 return (
  <BrowserRouter>
   <Routes>
    <Route index element={<Home />} />
    <Route path='/services' element={<Services />}>
     <Route path='/landscape' element={<Landscape />} />
    </Route>
   </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
 );
}

export default App;
```

**Services.js**

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom'

function Services() {
 return (
  <Container>
   <Row>
    <Col>Services</Col>
   </Row>
   <Outlet />
  </Container>
 );
}

export default Services;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Services` and `Landscape` routes are missing the closing tag. They can self-close, or have the closing tag added.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route index element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/projects" element={<Projects />}>
      <Route path="/construction" element={<Construction />}></Route>
      <Route path="/services" element={<Services />} />   // <-- close
      <Route path="/landscape" element={<Landscape />} /> // <-- close
    </Route>
    <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
    <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
    <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" replace />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: This fixed the error, but why does make it so the pages render as blank?

Comment: @calyxofheld Which pages are rendering blank? The `"/services"` and `"/landscape"` routes? Is the `Projects` component rendering an `Outlet` for the nested routes to be rendered into?

Comment: all pages render blank. right now i'm doing `Services` but it's functionally the same. `Outlet` is included in the `Services` component

Comment: @calyxofheld Can you create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces this issue we could inspect?